# Wordpress site on azure web app redirect to 404 error page

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, redirect, web-config

I've a wordpress based internet site hosted within an Azure web app.

In case I enter a various string behind the "/" of my URL (for instance: "www.blabla.net/asdfasdf") I get redirected to my configured 404 Error page. **BUT:** In case the URL string contains one or multiple "+" characters (for instance: "www.blabla.net/as+asdf" or just "www.blabla.net/+") the redirection to the configured 404 Error page doesn't work and I get redirected to a page containing the following text:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

My "web.config" file on the IIS 8 looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress: http://blabla.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                   <conditions>
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                   </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="index.php"/>
         </rule></rules>
        </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I would very appreciate it if you could give me any hint how to configure the web.config file in such a way that "+" characters are treated as the other various characters and the redirection is performed to the configured 404 Error page?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons, a URL request containing a double escape sequence will be rejected by the filtering module since IIS 7. That is why you have got a 404.11 Response code when you put a "+" character into the URL. You may refer to [this post](https://blogs.iis.net/thomad/iis7-rejecting-urls-containing) for the details.

If you insist on making a URL with a "+" character to work, you can use the `web.config` file as listed below. Then the `www.blabla.net/as+asdf` or  `www.blabla.net/+` will be redirected to the configured 404 Error page, but keep in mind this may somehow reduce the security level to your website.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress: http://blabla.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Aaron Chen: Thank you very much for the fast response! It works as expected now!